# How to stop or cancel execution of dispatch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, dispatch-async

I want to execute multiple dispatch block at same time. So when any dispatch block is in progress at same time when I run 2nd dispatch block, I want to stop execution of previous dispatch block.

I'm using this below code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:item.URL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         NSError *error = nil;
         self.player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        });
    });
```

And I also tried this below code. but if I used this below code it is possible to cancel previous block but my application goes hang

```
//Use NSOperationQueue 
    myQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // Background work
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:item.URL];
       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Main thread work (UI usually)
            NSError *error = nil;
           self.player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];
    }];
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The dispatch block in GCD cannot cancel, but the the block in NSOperationQueue can cancel.

Comment: @EricXuan :  Yes, I know `NSOperationQueue` is possible to cancel But when I used `NSOperationQueue` my application is stuck

Comment: @EricXuan - Actually, you now can cancel in GCD. (It's just not as elegant as the cancelation logic in `NSOperation`.) The problem is `dataWithContentsOfURL`, as that's not cancelable. He should use `NSURLSession`, which is cancelable. And he should lose GCD and/or `NSOperation` completely, or if he wants to keep it, he should use cancelable custom asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass, and have `cancel` method cancel the task (while this is a richer solution than just `NSURLSession` by itself, it's also a little more work).

Comment: @Moni_BQ - You can call cancel on `NSOperation`, but that's only half of the solution. You also have to write an asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass that actually responds to the cancellation events, or else the call to `cancel` won't cancel any operations that are underway (only effectively stopping those that have not yet started, which is of minimal value).

Comment: @Rob : I implement this functionality for play song online. Means I want to used this for  online streaming . So My question is that, using `NSURLSession` possible to manage online streaming?

Comment: You really want two things: You want to be able to cancel a download that is in progress (which is why you want to use `NSURLSession`, assuming that `item.URL` is a remote URL and not a local fileURL). You also want to be able to stop the playing of a song. So just call `stop` on the `AVAudioPlayer`. Neither GCD nor `NSOperation` are needed for either of these tasks. And you only use `NSURLSession` in lieu of `dataWithContentsOfURL` if `item.URL` is a remote web URL.

Comment: @Rob : Listen, what I exactly want to implement, I have 1 Song album that contains 10 songs. Now I play 3rd song from song list and when I click on 3rd song 1st dispatch block  is start execution and immediately I play next song(Still 1st song's dispatch block not completed his execution). Now sudden click on next song (now 1st and 2nd both song is still not  execute). Too much time is taken for when song play. `So I want when last song which is play by user only that dispatch block will execute and all other should  stop his execution `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113380/discussion-between-moni-bq-and-rob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No dispatch queues or operation queues are needed here.

You just need to be able to start an asynchronous download session with `NSURLSession` and when the download is successful, start the asynchronous `AVAudioPlayer`. And because those are asynchronous tasks, you can either `cancel` or `stop` them respectively.

Here is a trivial example:

```
@class Song;

@protocol SongDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)song:(Song *)song didFinishPlayingSuccessfully:(BOOL)flag;
- (void)song:(Song *)song didFinishDownloadWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface Song: NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   NSURLSessionTask *downloadTask;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *localURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   id<SongDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation Song

+ (instancetype)songWithURL:(NSURL *)url delegate:(id<SongDelegate>)delegate {
    Song *song = [[Song alloc] init];
    song.url = url;
    song.delegate = delegate;
    return song;
}

- (void)downloadAndPlay {
    self.downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:self.url completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.delegate song:self didFinishDownloadWithError:error];
        });
        NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:false error:&error];
        NSAssert(documentsURL, @"URLForDirectory failed: %@", error);
        NSURL *fileURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:self.url.lastPathComponent];
        NSError *moveError;
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:fileURL error:&moveError];
        NSAssert(success, moveError.localizedDescription);

        // note, the only reason we dispatch the following is that this completion handler runs on background queue and we want to update properties and start the player from the main queue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.localURL = fileURL;
            NSError *playError;
            self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&playError];
            self.player.delegate = self;
            [self.player play];
            NSAssert(playError == nil, playError.localizedDescription);
        });
    }];
    [self.downloadTask resume];
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self.downloadTask cancel];  // if download still in progress, stop it
    [self.player stop];          // if playing, stop it
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    self.player = nil;
    [self.delegate song:self didFinishPlayingSuccessfully:flag];
}

@end
```

So you can see that `downloadAndPlay` initiates asynchronous download and, when that's done, starts the asynchronous playing of the track. The `cancel` method cancels the download if in progress and stops the playing if in progress.

And then you can use it like so:

```
@interface ViewController () <SongDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) Song *song;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.song = [Song songWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.last.fm/static/1464677535/131211148/70b3b5a9d048c7939d5bb9ec87a2c5d58d6ee528828f5c6a5b7b1eddd69f4553/Death+Grips+-+Get+Got.mp3"] delegate:self];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)didTapPlayButton:(id)sender {
    [self.song downloadAndPlay];
}

- (IBAction)didTapStopButton:(id)sender {
    [self.song cancel];
}

- (void)song:(Song *)song didFinishPlayingSuccessfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"did finish playing %@", flag ? @"successfully" : @"unsuccessfully");
}

- (void)song:(Song *)song didFinishDownloadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"did finish download with error %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
@end
```

Now, clearly, this a trivial implementation (you don't really want to do `NSAssert` if you have any errors, but rather handle it gracefully, you want to handle a series of `Song` objects, you may want to decouple downloading from playing so that you can start downloading song 2 while song 1 plays, etc.), but it illustrates the broader concept of canceling either a download or the playing of a song, both of which are already asynchronous tasks, so no dispatch queues or operation queues are needed. You can do that if you want to get fancy, but that's a more advanced topic.

By the way, `NSURLSession` is pretty strict about prohibiting non-https requests because of the security risk they pose, but you can edit your `info.plist` (right click on it and then say "Open As" - "Source code") and then enter something like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>dl.last.fm</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks , Let me try your solution